# vite-nuxt error when added to Nuxt 2 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vite

I'm working on a Nuxt 2 project and I want to use vite instead of webpack.

I installed [nuxt-vite](https://github.com/nuxt/vite) and added it to `buildModules` and it worked but I got an error regarding JSX in some component:

```
[ERROR] The JSX syntax extension is not currently enabled

  <div
  ^

The esbuild loader for this file is currently set to "js" but it must be set to "jsx"
to be able to parse JSX syntax. You can use "loader: { '.js': 'jsx' }" to do that.
```

I installed `@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx` and added it to `vite` withing `nuxt.config`:

```js
vite: {
  plugins: [vueJsx({})]
}
```

Now I get a different error that I don't know how to solve

```
TypeError: vite.createFilter is not a function
```

These are the packages (only what I think is relevant to the question, I'll provide full list if needed)

```json
"devDependencies": {  
  "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.0",
  "nuxt-vite": "^0.3.5",
  "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
}
```